# Electron builder not packing module?

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

Hi all I'm working on an app that uses vue + electron builder,
but for some reason one of my modules **(@wuild/vue-electron-ipc)** cannot be found after packaging for production and I'm getting the following error

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@wuild/vue-electron-ipc'

Here is my package.json

```
  "name": "bla",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
  },
  "main": "./background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wuild/vue-electron-ipc": "^1.0.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "createjs": "^1.0.1",
    "electron-window-manager": "^1.0.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-vue": "^5.15.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jsonfile": "^2.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.13",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^9.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Can someone please help me?